# Including a global variable in a PHP object

Tags: php, class, scope

Hopefully this is a straight forward question:

I am looking to create a class, and I want to include my database variable ($mysql) in it so I can do DB interactions. So far, I've been making it global inside functions, but I'm hoping that rather then including the variable globally in every class function, there was some way to simply include it into the class/access it in the class. I'm not very good with scoping.

The only option I can think of is to create a class variable and in the constructor, include the variable globally and assign it (maybe by reference, does that make sense?) to the class variable.

Any other options?

Comment: Creating a class property to hold the database object, passed in the constructor, is a common and good solution, much better than calling it globally.  Objects are assigned by reference by default in PHP.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I suspected that may be the answer. That being given, is making it private fine? Or does this fit better as a static?

Comment: Private is fine, and `private static` may be necessary if you have other static methods in the class which require access to the database outside instance context. But in that case, you haven't called a constructor so you need some kind of `init()` method to set the static property. Don't worry about that though, if you only plan to use it in instance context.

Comment: That makes sense. Yah, its only in the context of the instance; I already have the DB object, I just need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I programmed this class for my database handling, maybe its a bit of use to you:

```
<?php
    class Database {
        public $mysqli;

        function __construct() {
            $this->connect();
        }

        function __wakeup() {
            $this->connect();
        }

        function connect() {
            $mysqli = new mysqli(MYSQL_SERVER, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, MYSQL_DB);
            if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->conect_errno . ')'
                    . $mysqli->connect_error);
            }
            mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, 'utf8');
            $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
        }   

        function queryDB($query) {
            $result = $this->mysqli->query($query);

            if ($this->mysqli->error) {
                error_log("QUERY ERROR: " .$this->mysqli->error);
                error_log("QUERY: " . $query);
            }
            return $result;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I made a class similar to this for my use. One thing that I did differently was declare the `connection` method as well as the `$mysqli` property static. This allows the class to share the connection across all instances and not re-connect every time the class is instanced.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood my question or I misunderstood your response. I already have a PDO instance to handle my database. I am making a different class to handle a particular dataset, and I would like to be able to directly make use that PDO instance rather then making a new connection, and so I want to figure out how I can include it.

Comment: @RhoVisions If you did like I said, new instances wouldn't re-connect to the database on every instantiation. Other than that, you would have to use some sort of "dependency injection" which is just fancy for "pass in an instance of the class as an argument to a method/function. Or pass into a class in constuctor that stores it as a property internally."

Comment: Allright, Sorry i got it wrong then. Couldn't you Extend your other Class to the Datebase Class, and accessing the instance with the parent:: function? maybe that's an option?

Comment: Jonathan: I'm not concerned about reconnecting, as I already have an active connection. The second half of your answer is what I was leaning to: what is the best method of including a global variable into an object.